# Printing on transparent sheet

Tags: printing, printer

I am using Samsung CLP 365. Can I use it to print on all transparent sheets or there are any special transparent sheets for printing using laser jet printers.

Comment: We have no way of knowing. You've not told us any printer information or what transparencies you're using. Not all transparencies are the same; some are laser printer compatible. [Edit] your question with more details if you'd like some help.

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

On the Samsung page for [this printer](http://www.samsung.com/hk_en/consumer/computer-peripherals/printers-multifunction/color-laser-printers/CLP-325W/XSS) it states;

> Paper Handling Media Type: A4, A5, A6, Letter, Legal, Executive,
>   Folio, ISO B5, JIS B5, **Transparency(Mono Print Only)**, Glossy Photo220
>   g/m2, Envelope, Labels, Cardstock, Recycled

(my emphasis added)

Now purchase [laser capable transparencies](http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/Meetings/Home/Products/Transparency_Film/) and you're all set.